# Minilla or Milla (Dist::Milla) - add to Build.PL

Tags: perl

I want to use [Minilla](https://metacpan.org/pod/Minilla) or [Milla](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Milla) to release my dist.
I want to check some condition before create `Build` script in Build.PL. But Minilla and Milla rewrite `Build.PL` every time when I run Minilla or Milla `build`. How I can do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create `ModuleBuild` extension like this:

```
package builder::SomeName;
use strict;
use warnings;
use parent 'Module::Build';

sub new {
    my ($class, %arg) = @_;

    # check some condition

    die "Not supported.\n"
        if !$check;

    $class->SUPER::new(%arg);
}
1;
```